# A question about extension of relative subvariety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X\rightarrow S$ be a holomorphic family of projective manifolds. My question is: can we find a Zariski open set $S'\subset S$ such that for any $t\in S'$, any given subvariety $Y\subset X_t$ with codimension $k$, there exists a relative subvariety $Z\subset X$ of codimension $k$ with $X_t\cap Z=Y $?

The motivation of this question is from Claire Voisin's proof of algebraic hyperbolicity of general hypersurfaces of degree large enough (in her article "On some problems of Kobayashi and Lang", proof of thm 3.3). The statement is as follows: Let $U$ be the Zariski open set parametrizing smooth hypersurfaces in $P^{n+1}$ of degree $d$.  Let $\pi: X\rightarrow U, X\subset P^{n+1}\times U$ be the universal family. Assume for a general $X_t$ $(t\in U)$ there is given a subvariety $Y\subset X$ of codimension $k$. Then there exist a quasi-projective variety $B$, a dominant morphism $\phi:B\rightarrow U$, and a relative subvariety  $Z\subset X_B$ of codimension $k$, where $X_B:=X\times_U B$, such that $Y\subset X_t$ is one fiber $Z_b$ for some $b\in B$.

My question is, how to prove the existence of this etale cover $\phi:B\rightarrow U$, and does this claim hold for any holomorphic family of projective manifolds?

Comment: No, that is not true, unless you allow $S'$ to be the empty set.  Consider the family of polarized K3 surfaces of some genus $g$, and consider the family of $(-2)$-curves contained in fibers.

Comment: @ Jason: Thanks. Can we add some conditions to make this statement to be true? In other word, when could this type of extension hold?

Comment: "Can we add some conditions to make this statement to be true?"  You could assume that $X$ is bimeromorphic to a trivial product $X_0\times S$.

Comment: It seems to me that Stacks Lemma 30.15.9 (1) here: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/056P is similar to what you want, when $k=1$. For $X\to S$ a flat family, if $Z_t\subset X_t$ is a Cartier divisor, then there is an open subset $U\subset X$ and a relative Cartier divisor $Z\subset U$ with $Z\cap X_t = Z_t$ (unless I am misunderstanding something!).

Comment: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/056Y may also be helpful: it seems to say that if you have a flat family $X\to S$ and a Cartier divisor $Z_t\subset X_t$ (at least locally around a point $x\in X_t$) then there is an affine $U\subset X$ and a divisor $Z$ such that $Z\cap X_t=Z_t$ and $Z\to S$ flat.

Comment: @RuadhaíDervan.  That lemma only produces a Cartier divisor in $U$.  It does not produce a Cartier divisor whose intersection with $X_t$ is a given Cartier divisor.  Indeed, there can be no such theorem, as follows by considering $(-2)$-curves on K3 surfaces.

Comment: Thanks. @JasonStarr I wonder if you could spell out the argument in the case that $X$ is birational to $X\times S$ (or provide some reference)?

Comment: @RuadhaíDervan: Actually, I might have spoken too soon.  Certainly for a product $X_0\times S$, it is possible to extend subvarieties.  However, already for the family of blowings up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at $9$ points, I suspect that the rational curves of negative self-intersection exhibit the same type of behavior as with K3 surfaces.  So I should not have suggested that there is a positive answer in the case of a "bimeromorphically trivial" fibration.

Comment: @Jason I think this is right.  If you fix 8 points and move the 9th in a line (or take any other reasonable curve in the Hilbert scheme), there countably many fibers in which a $(-2)$-curve appears, which I guess is what you need.

Comment: @Jason If we are allowed to pass an etale covering $U\rightarrow S$, could we have such an extension? In some sense, the question is more or less like to find sections of the natural projection $Hil(X/S)\rightarrow S$, maybe in the category of etale cover...